# Reinstalled MySQL, mysql_secure_install results in access denied

Tags: mysql, fedora

A few years ago I wanted to learn MySQL and installed MySQL Community on Fedora Linux. Today, I'm needing it for a project, but I can't remember any users or passwords. I removed it through dnf and installed it again. I started the server through systemctl and ran mysql_secure_installation. It prompted:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
```

I typed a new password and it issued an error:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I tried to remove MySQL again, delete the /var/lib/mysql folder and reinstall it again. Still, no success, it keeps issuing the same error.

Could anybody help me install MySQL and configure it properly, please?

Answer (score 0):

Im not using fedora, but i think same way as other linux

you should type console "mysql -u root -p" where -u is a user and -p is a password, I think you not used -p or maybe my mistake then need more information how did you try to access to database.

have a nice day :)

Comment: It results in acecss denied, I don't have the password anymore.

I'd be glad to provide more information, please tell me what else you need.

Comment: Besides the mysql_secure_installation, I tried to access the same way you suggested, using:

mysql -u root -p.

I don't have the password, though.

Comment: then the easiest way: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/, you have to set a new password, but will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I found this solution.

I am using mysql installed with homebrew.

1. First run this:

> ps aux | grep mysql

2. Then:

> kill $(pgrep mysql)

3. Finally

> mysql_secure_installation

Hope this will help you.